# Exporting a JSON String to file

Tags: android, json, file, export, phonegap

I created an Android mobile application using phonegap and I'm looking for a way to export the strigified json dataset. I strigified my json this way:

```
var storageObj = mydata.toGeoJSON();
var data = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(storageObj));
```

Then I tried:

```
var dlAnchorElem = document.getElementById('downloadAnchorElem');
dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("href",     data     );
dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("download", "data.js");
dlAnchorElem.click();
```

with

```
<a id="downloadAnchorElem" style="display:none"></a>
```

While it's working on a desktop pc, it doesn't on my mobile application.

How should I go about exporting the stringified json to a file and storing or (if it is easier to implement) sending it via email?

Answer (score 0):

Get the json
For JAVA, use Gson library.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String prettyJson = gson.toJson(json); 
    /**
     * Dump the json in file.
     */
try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("PATH/" + "YOUR_FILE_NAME.txt")){
        out.println( json);
}catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printstacktrace();
}
```

1. If you are using and android application put its dependency in the `build.gradle` file.[dependency details](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1)
2. For normal JAVA projects,[enter link description here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar) download the JAR.

Hope it helps.